# How to access the "Title" of a file from a BIM 360 "Plans" folder

Tags: autodesk-forge

We need to get the "Title" as seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCte0.png) in the Plans folder of the Document Management page of BIM 360.

So far I can only find it at `version.Value.attributes.extension.data.viewableName` where `version` is initialized as follows

```cs
ItemsApi itemApi = new ItemsApi();
itemApi.Configuration.AccessToken = Credentials.TokenInternal;
var versions = await itemApi.GetItemVersionsAsync(projectId, itemId);
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, dynamic> version 
    in new DynamicDictionaryItems(versions.data)) 
{
    var vieawbleName = version.Value.attributes.extension.data.viewableName
    ...
}
```

But it isn't always there. If it is there, viewableName will contain something like "A1.00 - SITE SURVEY", where "A1.00" is the "Number" of that item/version, and "SITE SURVEY" is the "Title". The issue is that most of the time, viewableName will only contain "Number" not "Number - Title".

Is there a way to get the "Title" consistently? Ideally, we would like to see the title for each version, in case it is changed from one version to the next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the title attribute is built via BIM360 custom attributes feature, and there is no API available to fetch it currently as I know. Sorry for the bad news.

Comment: Do you know if this is something that forge may support in the future? If so, do you have an idea of when this might happen?