# `versions:batch-get` doesn't fetch the "Title" Custom Attribute

Tags: autodesk-forge

I've been trying to get the "Title" attribute of documents within my projects' Plans folder, but the sheets `number`/`displayName` appears in the `title` field of the response:

```
{
  "urn": "urn:adsk.wipprod:fs.file:[...]version=1",
  "itemUrn": "urn:adsk.wipprod:dm.lineage:[...]",
  "name": "A13.3",
  "title": "A13.3", // <- Here
  "...": "...",
  "customAttributes": [], // <- Nothing here, even if I modify the "Title value"
  "number": "A13.3"
  
}
```

Is this intentional? Or have I misunderstood? I can't find any other endpoint which has documentation suggesting it'll fetch the `Title` attribute. I see that the BIM360 web app is using the [legacy endpoint](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360-private/v1/reference/http/projects-project_id-folders-folder_id-custom_attributes-GET) to fetch this property for itself:

`projects/:project_id/folders/:folder_id/custom_attributes`.

I know this is similar to a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56030673/how-to-access-the-title-of-a-file-from-a-bim-360-plans-folder), but it seems that was asked well over a year ago when there was no `versions:batch-get` endpoint.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The documentation you mentioned is out-of-date. Please check this one instead:

https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/document-management-versionsbatch-get-POST

The fields like `title`, `displayName` and `name` are Docs built-in custom attributes and will appear in response of [POST versions:batch-get](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/document-management-versionsbatch-get-POST) only, not in [GET custom-attribute-definitions](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/document-management-custom-attribute-definitions-GET/).

Besides, the `customAttributes` field of [POST versions:batch-get](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/document-management-versionsbatch-get-POST) and [GET custom-attribute-definitions](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/document-management-custom-attribute-definitions-GET/) are for [user-created custom attributes](http://help.autodesk.com/view/BIM360D/ENU/?guid=GUID-244FAB32-8E3B-4D1B-A1EB-C982DB93ABB3) only. If you don't assign any value to your user-created custom attributes to either the document or file of your Docs project, then `customAttributes` field will be empty. Here is the field description from the [documentation](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/document-management-versionsbatch-get-POST/#body-structure-200).

> The list of custom attributes for each document. For more information about custom attributes, see the Customize Documents with Attributes documentation.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm afraid I didn't explain what I'd tried very will in my question. The JSON snippet that I included is from the `versions:batch-get` endpoint. In the Plans folder of the Bim360 UI, the sheet's Title field is "UNIT B SECOND FLOOR REFLECTED CEILING PLAN", but `versions:batch-get` endpoint returns the sheet number for the Title field. Is this a bug, or am I still missing something?

Comment: Could you contact forge[DOT]help[AT]autodesk[DOT]com for this issue instead? We may need to schedule an online meeting to see what happened since I cannot reproduce this issue on my side.  Thanks!

Comment: Will do! Thank you!